# How can I copy terminal output from an ssh console and paste it into local windows notepad window

Tags: ssh

I have ssh'ed into a Linux console using the Cygwin ssh command. after running a command I need to copy several lines of the output and paste them into a windows notepad window.

The problem is that I cannot use the mouse in my ssh session because I am blind, so left-clicking and dragging to the bottom of the area to copy won't work for me.

Are there any keyboard ways to accomplish this?

BTW: I am trying to copy a 3 or 4 line randomly generated activation key for some software which I need to save.

An addition to this question is the command I am running presents this long activation key which actually has to be pasted into a website to generate a token which then has to be pasted into the terminal which is waiting for input after displaying the activation key.

I know I can use the right-click or ctrl+ins keys to paste the token back into the terminal, but I need to get the activation key.

Redirecting to a file won't work because of the second step of the process.

Comment: This is a MS-windows question, it has nothing to do with Unix or ssh, as these are not the components involved with the cut/copy. If you are running the ssh in a cmd window, then I believe that there is an option in the edit menu. Also in options you can enable quick-???? (can't remember the name) it allows you to `select right click` to copy, and `right click` to paste (or paste it somewhere else e.g. notepad). This is nearly as quick as the X11 select, then middle button to paste.

Comment: Oh I just read the 2nd paragraph, so my suggestion above will not work for you. I do not know the details (as I use `emacs`), but I believe that the `vi` editor would make life easier for you. It is a bit hard to learn, but very powerful, and does not use a GUI type interface.

Comment: You can also use `scp` part of `ssh`. It is a file copy command, it will allow you to copy a file from the remote to the local. It also uses same authentication as `ssh`, so if you have `ssh` access, you should have `scp` access. Example `scp user@remote-host:/path/to/file local-file-name`

Comment: @Richard,  vi is a reasonable solution, but I am not sure how it would work in this case.  I have been using vi for almost 20 years, although I am by no means an expert :)

Comment: The `vi` answer was focussing on getting the text in to a usable editor, that is usable by a blind person. I did not think about why you where doing it. This is why I added the `scp` answer, as it may be more use full for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a keyboard shortcut - <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> will open the Control menu for the active window, which will have an Edit sub-menu.  *Mark* will allow you to select an area, and the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will copy the selection to the clipboard for pasting elsewhere.  I do not know the keyboard shortcuts for demarking the selected area to be copied, and unfortunately do not have a Windows machine to hand upon which to experiment.

If the text you need to copy is the output of a command, you could redirect the output into a file (e. g. `/path/to/sometool > myfile.txt`) and then open that file in Notepad directly.

Comment: @dopghoti,  This is very workable provided the ssh session is originating from a windows system. I actually used the context menu for the window, selected edit -> select all, then <enter> to copy to the clipboard.

Comment: However, what if the host originating the ssh session is a *nix system, does it have similar keyboard functions to copy the entire console window into a clipboard?

Comment: If you are within a *nix GUI environment, there _may_ be such a keyboard shortcut, but that would depend upon the actual window manager in question (e. g. Gnome, KDE, twm, lxde, et cetera).

Answer (score 1):

To get a file from a remote machine that you have access to via `ssh`, and usable via a not visual interface.

You can use `scp` part of `ssh`. It is a file copy command, it will allow you to copy a file from the remote to the local. It also uses same authentication as `ssh`, so if you have `ssh` access, you should have `scp` access.

Example `scp user@remote-host:/path/to/file local-file-name`

Note both arguments can be local or remote.

Comment: Once again this is a good idea except that I am in the middle of an interactive application that simply displays one thing on the console that has to be copied and pasted into a browser and the response from the browser pasted back into the interactive application running in the console.